# Es recomendable establecer el margin y el padding a 0 en el documento css de mi pagina?

Tags: html5, css3

Tenia un problema con la visualización de mi pagina, el codigo que esta al final me lo resolvió, pero la persona que me dijo que hacer no me lo explico muy bien que digamos.

```
* {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: El selector * selecciona absolutamente todos los elementos de tu documento, por lo tanto todos tus elementos tienen un padding y margin de 0, no obstante no quiere decir que no pueda ser cambiado por otro valor, pero por defecto tienen ese estilo.

Comment: ¿La pregunta es si "es recomendable" o si no entiendes lo que hace dicho código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por defecto algunos elementos html tienen un padding y un margin. Al hacer el reset;

```css
* { 
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
```

estas eliminando todos los padding y los margin que vienen por defecto y los reseteas a 0, de esta manera cuando estes editando tu css podrás poner el margin y el padding que quieras a los diferentes elementos sin que un anterior padding o margin le afecte.

Si quieres puedes ver más sobre los valores por defecto de los elementos html en w3, https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp (fíjate por ejemplo que el elemento body tiene por defecto 8px de margen)

Es recomendable si quieres poner tus propios paddings y margins. Tienes que tener ademas en cuenta las otras etiquetas que pueden verse afectadas.

Comment: Dices que "por norma general sí es recomendable" ¿dónde o cómo puedes demostrar esto?

Comment: Es recomendable si quieres poner tus propios margenes. No es que sea una convención.

Answer (score 1):

Es muy común utilizar un bootstrap.css o reset.css para iniciar el css común. Digamos que cada motor de navegación puede aplicar a ciertos elementos unas reglas como el padding, para forzar "partir" de la misma base es común utilizar css como el que te pongo a continuación: [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css)